# Is there something similar to LINQ in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, database

I wonder if it is possible (and how) to provide a class in Objective-C with something like:

```
Person.Select(@"Name").OrderAsc(@"Name").Where(@"Id").EqualTo(1).And(@"Id").NotEqualTo(2).Load<Array>
```

That could be very handy for a project I'm doing.

I like this way of coding present in Django & SubSonic.

Comment: I would love a LINQ equivalent in Objective-C. Someone should write one!

Comment: @JonathanSterling - I have! https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC

Comment: @JonathanSterling, please check LINQ4Obj-C available on GitHub: https://github.com/michalkonturek/LINQ4Obj-C. You can find docs here: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/LINQ4Obj-C/1.0.0/

Comment: If you're using Swift, try https://github.com/prosumma/CoreDataQueryInterface. This is much more similar to LINQ than the other libraries because, like C# and unlike ObjC, it makes extensive use of the type system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that there is not an equivalent to Linq for Objective-C but you can fake it with a mix of SQLite, NSPredicate and CoreData calls in a wrapper class shaped to your liking.  You'd probably be interested in the [core data guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#/), the [predicate guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html), and [this example code](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/CoreRecipes/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003664).

From the above predicate guide:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee"
        inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
// assume salaryLimit defined as an NSNumber variable
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
        @"salary > %@", salaryLimit];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Answer (score 15):

I created my own Linq-style API for Objective C, which is [available on github](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC). Your specific example would look something like this:

```
NSArray* results = [[[people where:^BOOL(id person) {
                                return [person id] == 1 && [person id] != 2;
                             }]
                             select:^id(id person) {
                                return [person name];
                             }]
                             sort];
```

Comment: Under which license is your library available? Can I use it in commercial software?

Comment: @Zoidberg - good point, I had not indicated a licence. I have just updated the project to include an MIT licence, so this should be just fine for commercial use.

Comment: This is really good, it's very similar to linq except that it appears you are using anonymous methods instead of predicate?

Comment: Hi Nick, not sure what you mean? The library primarily uses blocks where Linq would use delegates / lambdas.

Comment: @ColinE Blocks is just another name for anonymous functions?

Comment: Correct, same concept, different name!

Answer (score 5):

There is an acticle comparing the Windows and Cocoa ways of doing this. Cocoa uses Key Paths And NSPredicate....

[Cocoa is my Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/08/24/cocoa-tutorial-c-linq-or-cocoa-key-paths-and-nspredicate/)

Answer (score 3):

I think specific to your example this would be the equivalent in Cocoa:

```
NSArray *people = /* array of people objects */

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Id = 1 AND Id != 2"];
NSSortDescriptor *byName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[byName autorelease]];

NSArray *matches = [people filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
NSArray *sortedMatches = [matches sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

NSArray *justNames = [sortedMatches valueForKey:@"Name"];
```

It's a little more verbose than the LINQ example and some of my lines could have been combined but to my eye this is easier to parse.

Answer (score 3):

My project, **LINQ4Obj-C**, ports LINQ standard query operators to Objective-C.

You can find it on [github](https://github.com/michalkonturek/LINQ4Obj-C) and its [docs here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/LINQ4Obj-C/1.2.0/). This library is also available through [CococaPods](http://cocoapods.org/?q=LINQ).

Source code of this project is available under the standard MIT license.

Your example would look this:

```
id results = [[[people linq_where:^BOOL(id person) {
    return ([person ID] == 1);
}] linq_select:^id(id person) {
    return [person name];
}] linq_orderByAscending];
```

**NB** I removed second condition (ID != 2) as it is pointless.

At the moment the library provides extension methods (categories) for collection classes, but in future I will also extend its functionality to `NSManagedObjectContext` to provide direct query access to Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following repository: https://github.com/ziminji/objective-c-sql-query-builder

These classes provides a set of convenience methods that can be used to build well-formed SQL queries quickly for Sqlite.  They are quite simple to use and are relatively straight forward since they follow basic SQL syntax.