# How to determine if object with given property exists in nsarray / nsmutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray

I have a NSMutableArray, and I want to check if there is an object there with a certain property set to a specific value. For example, the array is filled with users, and I want to check if there is an object with variable user_id set to 67. Is there a way to do this with blocks or predicates or something without having to loop through the array?

Comment: This question has some useful insights: http://stackoverflow.com/q/428542/1316346

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding a particular instance in an array by a property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867248/finding-a-particular-instance-in-an-array-by-a-property)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This did the trick from the afore mentioned link!

```
NSArray *people = /* array of people objects */

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Id = 1 AND Id != 2"];

NSArray *matches = [people filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Comment: I believe this is going to be slower then using a `for` and exiting it when you find a value.

Comment: If you need only the *existence* then `[array indexOfObjectPassingTest:...]` might be more effective, as it does not build a new array.

Comment: In my case I ended up needing the element anyway